# Android nfc send message to to and from HCE?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I want to implement p2p between two android apps using NFC.

I have tried the cardemulator (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CardEmulation) and cardreader (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CardReader) Apps. they work fine.

But in this example it's only send data from cardemulator to cardreader.
I want to do the other way as well.

Is it possible to send extra data within the apdu command?
The data-field now contain the aid, if I change this or put extra data after the aid, my app will off course change aid, so it will not connect.

Should I send an extra apdu command with my data?

or is it not possible to do so?

Comment: have you solved in same way?

Comment: What do you mean??, I haven't solved it. Now I can only send in one direction (by reading the emulated card).

Comment: I would know of you have tried and found a solution with apdu commands, if so let me know please

Answer (score 1):

NFC Peer 2 Peer mode is not the same thing of NFC Card Reader mode.

If you want to send data between two Android App you need Android Beam to operate in Peer 2 Peer mode.

Start from here to read some about [`LLCP` and `SNEP` protocols](http://members.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/).

Basically what you need is to send `NDEFMessage` from one device to the other using Android callback methods.

To send a `NDEFMessage` with Android Beam you need to implement these two interfaces:

```
CreateNdefMessageCallback
OnNdefPushCompleteCallback
```

Into `createNdefMessage()` method you must create and return a `NDEFMessage` to send ([here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ndef) you can find a description).

Into `onNdefPushComplete()` method you can do something on `NDEFMessage` sending complete.

What you need is to identify which device will act as Initiator, then into `createNdefMessage()` you should return a NDEFMessage to send to the other device.

On the receiving device (in NFC named Target device) you should receive `NDEFMessage` into `Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)` and manage that.

After that you can do the same thing on the other side.

Theoretically using SNEP protocol you should be able to send SNEP GET requests, but on Android this functionality have been disabled. Here you can read a discussion about [Android SNEP implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399806/how-to-a-send-snep-get-request-from-android)

Keep in mind that to be able to receive a NDEFMessage you must define an IntentFilter into yout manifest.xml specifying which NDEFMessage your activity must "intercept". This is an example to catch AndroidApplicationRecord NDEFMessage:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/com.example.android.beam" />
</intent-filter>
```

Check this [Android Beam Example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/2f33e1eae0671cc1aa3d367f8d900b532f6ca80f/samples/AndroidBeamDemo/src/com/example/android/beam/Beam.java)

Hope that helps

Comment: I know, but I don't want to use Android beam. So it is possible to interact with the reader, without pushing on the screen. Thats why I look at android reader and HCE.

Comment: @Han have to done this ? send data without using of Android Beam. I am got confused and don't know how to do it. because Android 10 deprecated Android Beam for NDEF message transfer.